# catch PDFBox warnings when loading erroneous PDFs

Tags: java, pdfbox

when loading a PDF with PDFBox one gets log-level warnings if the PDF is erroneous:

```
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load (new File (filename));
```

For example, this could lead to the following output on the console:

```
Dez 08, 2020 9:14:41 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser validateStreamLength 
WARNING: The end of the stream doesn't point to the correct offset, using workaround to read the stream, stream start position: 3141, length: 1674, expected end position: 4815
```

Obviously, the pdf has some errors in the content stream, but it does load into `doc`. But would it be possible to catch this warnings programmatically with PDFBox? Do some properties exist which tell you about the warnings after the document has been loaded?

I've tried [PDFBox-Preflight](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html), but that checks for PDF/A compliance, which leads to much more messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the non-lenient mode of the parser. This code is from the ShowSignature.java example:

```java
RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream raFile = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(file);
// If your files are not too large, you can also download the PDF into a byte array
// with IOUtils.toByteArray() and pass a RandomAccessBuffer() object to the
// PDFParser constructor.
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(raFile);
parser.setLenient(false);
parser.parse();
PDDocument document = parser.getPDDocument();
```

Comment: This solution is not working with the file attached in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5062

Comment: The answer here is about "not being lenient". Your JIRA question is that you want leniency for some file with broken encryption. This is unrelated.