# How to further process a buggy / malformed PDF that cannot be parsed by Tika / PDFBox but can by Evince / Libre Office Draw?

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika

My program is reading documents with Tika 2.24 to extract their contents.

Yet some PDFs (maybe buggy or malformed) cannot be processed by PDFBox although Evince, Libre Office Draw or even Gimp can open them.

I cannot share these PDFs but what I can tell is that they used to trigger [a StackOverFlow Error as described on Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4623) with PDFBox 2.0.25 and now trigger an IOException with PDFBox 2.0.26 :

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Possible recursion detected when dereferencing object 29 0

Consequently now that an IOException can be caught it is tempting to try and process a malformed PDF differently from the first parsing that triggered the IOException.

I read [that PDFBox offers a way to handle malformed PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196613/6351897) by setting `setLenient(true)` on a parser but could not find a way to set such leniency in Tika.

By the way I followed [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196613/6351897) with both  `setLenient(true and false)` but the IOException still appears.

Edit : following KJ's suggestion I ran pdftotext which output the following warnings :

> Syntax Error (5602): Object '29 0 obj' is being already parsed
> Syntax Error (5603): Bad 'Length' attribute in stream
> Syntax Error (8596): Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length
> Syntax Error (16945): Object '35 0 obj' is being already parsed
> Syntax Error (16946): Bad 'Length' attribute in stream
> Syntax Error (23267): Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length
> Syntax Error (23332): Object '37 0 obj' is being already parsed
> Syntax Error (23333): Bad 'Length' attribute in stream
> Syntax Error (28645): Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length

(Please note : there are 4 pages which seem to be malformed as PDFSam cannot export them separately).

Opening the pdf file in Text Editor as suggested by KJ did only reveal a single hit for "29 0 obj". Using `mutool show -be mypdf.pdf 29` outputs a `warning: PDF stream Length incorrect` and then the compressed content.

[QPDF check]
Still following KJ advices, running QPDF with `check` flag yields:

> checking myPDFWithIssues.pdf
> PDF Version: 1.5
> File is not encrypted
> File is not linearized
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (offset 5602): loop detected resolving object 29 0
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 29 0, offset 5552): /Length key in stream dictionary is not an integer
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 29 0, offset 5603): attempting to recover stream length
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 29 0, offset 5603): recovered stream length: 2983
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (offset 16945): loop detected resolving object 35 0
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 35 0, offset 16895): /Length key in stream dictionary is not an integer
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 35 0, offset 16946): attempting to recover stream length
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 35 0, offset 16946): recovered stream length: 6311
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (offset 23332): loop detected resolving object 37 0
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 37 0, offset 23282): /Length key in stream dictionary is not an integer
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 37 0, offset 23333): attempting to recover stream length
> WARNING: myPDFWithIssues.pdf (object 37 0, offset 23333): recovered stream length: 5302

Yet the faulty PDF has been regenerated by another user (from the same sources) and the newer PDF does not show any warnings. So issue will be hard to track!

So my question is : how can I process with Tika / PDFBox malformed PDFs that trigger the aforementioned IOException related to possible recursion ?

Any hint appreciated

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question for analysis?

Comment: @KJ thanks for the suggestion, I will try pdftotext as a last resort if I don't find anything else with Tika / PDFBox.

Comment: @mkl Unfortunately I can't. I know it's an ODT printed as PDF with PDFSam Basic 4..2.3 (producer SamBox 2.2.13) whiich is made of text and full page size scans. I tried to export it as PDF with LibreOffice Draw or with `pdftk burst` command but the problem vanished. Yet I tried to split it into pages with PDFSam 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 and a stackoverflow error appeared when exporting page 4 which is made of text. I will try and get the source ODT to see if there is a watermark or something like that.

Comment: @KJ Opening in text editor did not show duplicates (see my edit).

Comment: @mkl I could not reproduce the problem on a document that could be shared. This document comes from 3 different files (2 pdf and 1 docx so no odt as I assumed initially) that are merged together with PDFSam.

Comment: Hm.. In that case i assume that there already is some issue in one of the source files merged, and that issue worsened in the merge. Without analyzing the file itself, i don't see how to proceed. But even with such an analysis I'm not sure whether one can find a simple tweak to make PDFBox process your file.

Comment: @mkl now the PDF has been regenerated and the warnings are gone. On the original faulty pdf, `qpdf --check` shows `Length key in stream dictionary is not an integer`. Does it give you a hint ? By the way if you want me to test this faulty pdf against new pdfbox code I can do it.

Comment: If the **Length** is not an integer, then stream reading becomes error prone. And if it happens to be a reference to the stream object itself, that would also explain the *possible recursion* detected by PDFBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way I employed was to use external command line tool `pdftotext` (from package `poppler-utils` on Debian / Ubuntu) as suggested by @KJ in their (now deleted) comments.

Comment: Thanks @KJ, I ran `qpdf --check` and it found issues that it could resolve. For now I don't want to bring in a pdf repairing step into the text extraction process.